# Зная pid процесса получить Handle

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, wmi

Как, зная pid процесса получить Handle? pid получаю с помощью WMI, и всё бы хорошо, но в WMI нету handle (заголовка окна). Например, когда хром открываем, и там пустая вкладка. Вот нужно получить имя этой вкладки.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Wnd: hWnd;
  buff: array[0..127] of Char;
begin
  ListBox1.Clear;
  Wnd := GetWindow(Handle, gw_HWndFirst);
  while Wnd <> 0 do begin {Не показываем:}
    if (Wnd <> Application.Handle) and {-Собственное окно}
      IsWindowVisible(Wnd) and {-Невидимые окна}
      (GetWindow(Wnd, gw_Owner) = 0) and {-Дочернии окна}
      (GetWindowText(Wnd, buff, sizeof(buff)) <> 0) {-Окна без заголовков}
      then
    begin
      GetWindowText(Wnd, buff, sizeof(buff));
      ListBox1.Items.Add(StrPas(buff));
    end;
    Wnd := GetWindow(Wnd, gw_hWndNext);
  end;
  ListBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
end;
```

Вот код который получает список всех окон. Но мне нужно конкретного...

Comment: Так вам нужен handle процесса или конкретного окна? У одного процесса может быть куча окон. И хендлы у них, естественно, разные.

Comment: Я так понял, мне нужно использовать GetWindowText. Но как мне в него передать pid??

Comment: OpenProcess принимает PID, возвращает хэндл процесса.

Comment: Эм... и как можно это реализовать???

Comment: GetWindowText принимает хендл окна. Окон может быть много, чтобы найти их применяют EnumChildWindows . Это даст хендлы всех окон. Чтобы понять, принадлежит ли окно нужному процессу - использовать GetWindowThreadProcessId. Ну а как вы поймете,  что из 100500 окон нужного процесса вот это конкретное является окном вкладки - это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: При запуске приложения я получаю его FEventResult.TargetInstance.ProcessId.  Мне нужно только получить его заголовок.

Comment: Нет у приложения заголовка. Заголовок есть у окна. А у процесса окон много. Как визуальных, так и не визуальных. Поэтому первоочередная задача - вычленить из всех окон нужные (принадлежащие этому процессу), а дальше уже фильтровать их. Как это сделать - я уже написал. Еще раз: у процесса не одно, а **много** окон. "Главного" среди них нет, они равноправны.

Comment: Вот у этой вкладки заголовок :"delphi - Зная pid процесса получить Handle - Stack Overflow на русском". Вот с помощью кода который я выложил я получаю ее название. Но он мне выдаёт все заголовки окон активных. Я знаю pid мне нужен просто заголовок...

Comment: Мне не нужны все))) Да и не только хрома)))
@kami

Comment: Используйте EnumWindows (показать базовые окна) + GetWindowThreadProcessId. Детки редко нужны.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну, как сказать - редко. Я сейчас поленился, не посмотрел иерархию окон Хрома, но почему-то мне кажется, что окно конкретной вкладки - это дитё (хоть и может сидеть в отдельном процессе).

Comment: Добавьте в свой фильтр еще одно условие `(GetWindowThreadProcessId(что-там-надо-передать) = ваш-PID-полученный-из-WMI)`

Comment: да я в пример хром привел))) Но по сути когда пустую вкладку открываешь то да, этот момент не ловится WMI. Но если перейти по ссылки допустим с гугла на сайт. То создается новый процесс.

Не обязательно хром. Любое приложение.